spring-boot and Tomcat compatibility
Spring boot 3.3.2 and tomcat 11.0.0-M22
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer.lambda$customizeRejectIllegalHeader$21(TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer.java:227)

The following method did not exist:

   'void org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.setRejectIllegalHeader(boolean)'

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer and org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol


upgraded Spring boot 3.3.2 and tomcat 11.0.0-M22

Spring Boot 3.3 does not support Tomcat 11 milestones. You should use Tomcat 10.1 with Spring Boot 3.3.
